# Do the wso2-apps on centos require to install tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, wso2

I have a Centos server with JDK installed and the latest version of wso2am and wso2ei. I also opened ports 9444 and 9445 and started wso2amserver

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64; 
sh wso2/am/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2am/2.6.0/bin/wso2server.sh start -DportOffset=1 > wso2/amlogstart.txt 
sh wso2/ei/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/bin/wso2server.sh start -DportOffset=2 > wso2/eilogstart.txt
```

But I cannot connect. Does WSO2am require me to install Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSO2 products do not require a separate installation of Tomcat. Unfortunately connection issues can be caused by a multitude of things, from firewalls to ports already being in use.

Also, it looks like you are using the wrong command to start your product.  For EI you would need to start integrator.sh from the bin folder and not wso2server.sh. So they might not actually be running.

Comment: The cause was a port that was not open, in contrast to our believe. You are absolutely right, 'integrator' is the command for EI. Thanks. We have it up and running now.